# MySQL Session sql_mode vs Global sql_mode

Tags: mysql

`@@SESSION.sql_mode` and `@@GLOBAL.sql_mode` is showing different options.

**@@SESSION.sql_mode**

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

**@@GLOBAL.sql_mode**

```
NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

It seems like `GLOBAL.sql_mode` is taking precedence, is that right?

Why wouldn't a session setting overwrite a global setting?

**Query ran**:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode, @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It is extremely strange. Session variable value must override global one. Initially global values are copied into session ones, and the last are used. While overriding new session values uses. I have never seen global settings priority... can you demonstrate this by some way? Show console output, for example...

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  (There were changes. at least in 5.7.5.)

Comment: The **first** thing you do is to enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` - otherwise you will get inconsistent (i.e. **wrong**) results using `GROUP BY`. Do you have any settings in your my.cnf (or my.ini) that might change these settings?

Comment: @RickJames it's v5.6.26

Comment: Is the `@@SESSION.sql_mode` pertaining to my client that I use to run the query? Does that mean I might get a different value if I run the same query from my application? I mean, there's my app, and then there's my DB client that I use to run queries etc. Are the sessions different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Session" variables apply to the *connection*.  (Usually, there is exactly one connection per client.)  Two different clients (or different connections in one client) *may* have different values in the variables.

"Global" variables are defaults that are copied into "session" when you connect.  Then you, or your client code, or the 3rd party application, or whatever, could change the variables.

Note:  *Some* global variables are really global -- the "session" value always tracks the global copy.

If you display the *session* value from the *same connection*, then that is what the connection is using.  If you make a separate connection to read the value, then what you see may not be what is in effect.

There are hundreds of 3rd party packages out there; who knows what each of them does.  Furthermore, things change from version to version of that package.

`sql_mode` can be changed in a session.

In your example, *something in the connection* added `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` to `SQL_MODE`.  And it should be in effect for the connection until it is changed again.